# Extract contacts and messages from a Nokia 105 full dump (.bin) file

Tags: hex, decode, nokia, bin, firmware

Have a problem where I had to read the complete firmware (using an eeprom reader) from a hardware disabled (beyond repair) Nokia 105 (RM-908) in order to try and extract SMSes and the contacts. Using a hex editor I can see the all the data, however,I cannot manage to find out the complete information. For instance the date and receiver of the messages or the user associated with the contact numbers. The only idea I believe that can be done is to extract the personal user area PMM from the bin, get another set with the same version of this disabled device, build up an image, flash the resulting image using an appropriate flasher in the working device and read the content off this device. While I am unsure if this will work (theoretically might work), would like to try to avoid this procedure as it is very time consuming and maybe get to the target data directly via hex editing or any other application.

thanks for any help

Comment: It might help if we could see a sample of the data.  Also, there have been several `Nokia 105`s.  Can you point to a particular model?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Wallyk. The model is the RM-908.  I am trying to find the User Data Header to spot where the message starts or the message center. Unsure if Nokia uses GSM 03.38 to encode the messages in such a simple phone.